# Need to switch 2 tabs in Chrome browser in Karate UI

Tags: user-interface, automation, karate

Please, help me. I am stuck in tabs switching.
The problem - when I click the button (real site behavior), the new page is opened in the new tab and I am redirecting to the new tab too. But when I execute the test, debugging shows, that I am on the same page, that I wasn't redirected to the new one. I need to switch to the new opened tab in Karate.

I tried to use these commands ->

```
back()
forward()
switchPage()
```

And I can't find the way.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[`switchPage()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#switchpage) should work, try with the title or URL.

Else please follow this process so that we can fix it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

EDIT: we opened an issue to make this easier: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1210

so now this will work:

```
* driver 'https://mail.ru/'
* waitFor('.news-main__title').click()
* switchPage('news.mail.ru')
* match driver.title == 'Mail.ru: почта, поиск в интернете, новости, игры'
```

It will be great if you build from source and validate, so we can confirm: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Else you may need to wait a week for the next RC release.

Comment: Thx for the answer!

I tried this command. I put the page's title (URL I tried too) and Karate showed that the tests were passed, but after I put (with needed delay) this line to check current status ->

And match getUrl() contains 'part of my link',

I saw that I still on the same page.

Comment: @PavelMatveev well. you can keep trying or you can help us replicate the problem. you decide

Comment: The only problem, that news are changing. It must be adjusted to the test.

Comment: Thx, Peter! Unfortunatelly, it is not working for me. After the line -> switchPage('news.mail.ru'), I still on the initial page, I am not on the new one -> https://mail.ru/. And THX for opening an issue!

Comment: @PavelMatveev I meant it will work after you take the new version !

Comment: Thx a lot, Peter, for the help!