# Switch Page Karate UI issue

Tags: karate

I am having an issue with switching tabs using Karate UI. My code is as follows:

```
  Scenario: SwitchPage Test
    Given driver 'original URL'
    * retry(5, 10000).waitFor('#someID')
    * input('#someID', ['numbers', 'input', Key.ENTER]) // this will open the new page
    * print driver.title \\ this prints the original title of the original URL
    * switchPage('NewURL')
    * delay(10000) // I've put this just in case but it doesn't work without it either
    Then print driver.title // this still prints the original title of the original URL
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I think it is a great tool but I'm having difficulty with this scenario and our application opens new tabs with every module.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I know this can be hard. In 0.9.6 we have an option to switch tab by a) index and b) sub-string of the URL of that tab

Do consider submitting a simple example that can help us simulate and improve Karate if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Finally I recommend this option if possible. If there is some way for you to derive the URL of the tab that *will* get opened, try to re-use the current tab, and that makes for a simpler test. See this thread for more details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1269#issuecomment-682553602

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727612/143475

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I would submit it but the issue is that it is an internal application and thus I can't really submit the code. I am actually using 0.9.6. Any way you could provide me with an example of index/sub-string as I didn't see it in the documents. My apologies if I missed it.

Comment: @AlexArkanov yes, try `switchPage(0)` or 1. if you read the process, we just need you to simulate the link + js in a simple starter skeleton app. it should take you a few minutes to study your existing app and port only a few lines, your call

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply I'll try to mess around with it and make it work, otherwise I'll reach out to one of my devs to see if I can get a skeleton app so that this can be re-created.