# Karate-UI automation : Able to Switch page but not able to identify elements on that new page

Tags: automation, ui-automation, karate

I have a scenario in which after I click on link a new page is opened and then I need to work on the new page which is loaded.
Using **switchPage** I'm able to navigate to that page but it is not identifying the element on new page whereas it is searching for the element in the first page which is opened.

I'm not able to find a way to solve this problem. Can someone please help?

```
Scenario: Title of your scenario
Given driver baseUrl
    And waitFor("input[name='username']")
    And input("input[name='username']",username)
    And input("input[type='password']",password)
    When click("input[name='Login']")
    And waitFor("a[title='Setup']")
    When click("a[title='Setup']")
    * delay(2000)
    When switchPage(1)
    And waitFor("input[class='filter-box input']")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible we have a regression in 1.0.1 - see this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1606

The most helpful thing you can do is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue (ideally contribute code)

Alse see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706655/143475

Comment: Any possibility that I can close page 1 after page 2 is opened? This approach can allow me to proceed furthur.

Comment: @QaExpert you can try what is given in the above links. if `close()` works great, else it is a bug, maybe - I don't remember

Comment: close() works but even if page 1 is closed objects are not identified from page 2(which is the current page)

Comment: @QaExpert I repeat. try 1.1.0.RC3 and you still see an issue, it is a bug - and please follow the process