# Unable to do any action after switching to a new window using Karate

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I am not able to proceed with performing any action after switching to the new window.I am using  0.9.6

Then switchPage('Page Title')

- karate.log("driver.url", driver.url) [gives me the new window url]

## below is where it fails since it did not identify the locator

```
And waitFor('locator on the new page') [Fails]
```

I know there was a similar issue posted last month but with no resolution. Since I am not able to comment on it, I had to post a new question.
[Karate-UI automation : Able to Switch page but not able to identify elements on that new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67635891/karate-ui-automation-able-to-switch-page-but-not-able-to-identify-elements-on)

Answer (score 0):

Please try 1.1.0.RC2 and confirm if it is fixed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1606

Comment: ok..I am running into issues while upgrading to new version, hence asked nathanchilton who had similar issues to specify details of his POM..There are two places I see version in my POM.  Do I need both dependencies below? <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
     <artifactId>karate-ui</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.5.RC3</version><groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
   <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.6</version>

Comment: @janettemenezes that sounds wrong. follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thing is I cant submit my code, all I need is a clarification on how to mention the verison name in the POM if its an RC version..Referring to your POM in the UI exmaple test https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/examples/ui-test/pom.xml , should I be setting the version like this below? <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <karate.version>1.1.0.RC2</karate.version>
    </properties>

Comment: @janettemenezes as far as I can tell from here - yes

Comment: So now, I am able to download all dependancies with no errors, but looks like with the new version--Calling a feature file from a different folder is  throwing an exception org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException:. Errors out on this line * call read('classpath:path of the feature file')...I have seen comments in the past that calling feature files from different folder had issues and you had suggested to use 0.9.6 version...Let me know ..Thanks

Comment: Looks like the issue is reading anything from an external file..I tried running just one feature file with reading data from csv [  * def testdata = read(csvFileName)   ] so that itself fails..I am unable to proceed further..Appreciate your help.

Comment: @janettemenezes nope I give up. if you can, follow the process above to submit an issue else you are on your own

Comment: Issue was with using classpath, didnt know that I had to use file:'path of the external file'..Able to successfully get the external data..Continuing to test the actual problem and will keep you posted here and if I need further help, will definitely submit an issue..Thank you for such a wonderful tool and your patience in answering questions.!