# Is there any way to grab window handles of browser in Karate?

Tags: karate

I am facing an issue wherein my application after clicking on a certain link, opens up a new window where I do some set of UI actions which automatically closes the window (expected), and then I have to switch back to the first window for further actions; I couldn't find any way in karate to achieve this.

here is the exception that I am getting while trying to switch back on the first window -

```
   js failed:
    >>>>
    01: switchPage('test')
    <<<<
    org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: failed to get reply for: [id: 391, sessionId: A19C03C4EFF27570F8D56B8FF8F4639E, method: Target.getTargets]
    - com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.sendAndWait(DevToolsDriver.java:161)
    - com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsMessage.send(DevToolsMessage.java:213)
    - com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsMessage.send(DevToolsMessage.java:209)
    - com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.lambda$switchPage$7(DevToolsDriver.java:866)
    - com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions.retry(DriverOptions.java:509)
    - com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.switchPage(DevToolsDriver.java:865)
    - <js>.:anonymous(Unnamed:1)
```

Note - I am using karate 1.1.0

Comment: please consider contributing code to improve this in karate if needed. for now the only suggestion I have is open a new tab and not a window, use JS if needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706655/143475

Comment: Opening window2 is not in my hands ideally it's the expected behaviour of an application. Seems JS won't work in this case. With the new updated version of karate, switch Page working as expected, but my case is a bit different here where my window2 is getting closed after certain uI actions.

Comment: ideally yes. but in my opinion, it is okay to take some short-cuts for test-automation and the links give you plenty of options. if you feel so strongly about this I really hope you can put that energy into contributing code and a PR or two. it will make things better for everyone.