# Not able to maximize the window after switching page using Karate UI - Automation

Tags: ui-automation, karate

Able to maximize the first window but not able to maximize the new browser window.

```
Given driver 'https://applicationURL
And driver.maximize() #able to maximize the window here
And input('input[name=signOnName]', 'USERNAME')
And input('input[name=password]', 'CREDENTIALS')
When submit().click('input[id=sign-in]')
* delay(5000)
* submit().input("//input[@name='commandValue']", 'ENQ STATUS' + Key.ENTER)
# on pressing Enter Key, it open browsers in new window
* delay(5000)
When switchPage('AGENT.STATUS')
* driver.maximize() # This is not maximizing the new window
```

Comment: also please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706655/143475