# Unreachable page URL is not getting in karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to get the access code from the url, but in my scenario after clicking on submit button, the URL is unreachable(redirected to localhost/).So url is not coming due to unreachable page, i had tried both the following ways to get the url but no luck.

```
    * waitForUrl('/verified')
    * def actualUrl = driver.url
```

is there any alternative for this?

Comment: see if this answer gives you some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706655/143475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, nothing was helping me in this so got the text from the body tag, and from there I fetched the required code.

```
def item = text("//body[@id='test']/script[1]")
```

In case this may help someone.