# How can I manage Cross Origin Tests in Karate UI Automation

Tags: karate, ui-automation, webautomation

```js
Feature: Test Senetel Webapp

    Scenario: Login with incorrect credentials
        Given configure driver = {type: 'chrome', addOptions:["--remote-allow-origins=*"], port: 9515, executable: 'C://Program Files//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe'}"
      When driver 'https://fmsso-acpt.fanniemae.com/'
      And driver.maximize()
      And delay(3000)
      And input("#username","d33k4cnt")
      And input("#password","Dec_2023")
      And delay(3000)
      And click("//a[@id='signOnButton']")
      And delay(3000)
      And driver 'https://web.pr360b.sfbu.acpt.intgfanniemae.com/#/home'
      And delay(12000)
      And waitForUrl("https://web.pr360b.sfbu.acpt/#")
```

https://fmsso-acpt.fanniemae.com/ ->  this is my login page and once I login, the url changes to this one
https://web.pr360b.sfbu.acpt/# which is the home page.

Now, I want to access the elements on the home page but I cannot access them because of the cross origins.
Can someone please tell if karate UI automation can do cross origin tests.
If yes, how will I be able to do that?

Comment: I know teams that switch domains all the time, so this is something about the sites you are trying to test, maybe they have some extra JS for security. sorry, you are on your own here, I think the best possible reference is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706655/143475

Comment: I have tried it with Cypress and Selenium and everything is accessible with these tools. There is no extra JS security.
If some of the teams are doing it, then please at least tell me how to do it.
I can sort something out from that.
Also, the reference you have provided is not helpful here.

Comment: if you can provide a live URL where we can try it I will gladly help, you can see similar issues addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76680593/143475

Comment: Here is the URL:
https://web.pr360b.sfbu.acpt.intgfanniemae.com

Comment: I can't access it - it says blocked and when I run a test it says `Request Rejected` clearly this URL is not designed for public access.