Switching control to a new window in Karate
I am very new to this tool and need help in switching control over to a new window. After I click on a certain button on my original url, a completely new window, not tab opens up and I need to switch controls over it and take a screenshot. The test is passing but the screenshot is still taken off the original urls web page not the new window’s
I tried using switchpage() with both index and title as the parameter but it is not working. The test is passing but it does not look like switchpage was actually executed

this can be hard depending on JS involved. this thread may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706655/143475
