# How I can open and close next/new tab in active browser session in Karate UI Automation

Tags: karate

I am having a use case where I need to open a new tab in same browser session opened. Please guide me how I can achieve the same to open and close the new tab in same active session of browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JS:

```
* script("window.open('https://www.w3schools.com', '_blank')")
```

Also refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727612/143475

Comment: Notice that this may throw an error instead, which is similar to this:
`{code=-32000, message=Object reference chain is too long}`. I suppose this is because then the result of window.open is evaluated and it is HUGE. TO prevent the problem, just `* script("window.open('https://www.w3schools.com', '_blank').name")` which will return empty string or something like that.