# Unable to handle Sign in Dialog for SAML redirect using Karate Framework (UI)

Tags: karate

Unable to handle Sign in pop up window for SAML redirect using Karate Framework (UI)

Tried * dialog(false) and it did not close the popup. Not able to figure out on how to do keyboard ESCAPE as  input('body', Key.ESCAPE) did not work either.
Appreciate if someone had similar issue and resolved it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTJvG.png

Answer (score 0):

UI testing is hard. In these cases, the recommendation is that you sign-in using the API and then navigate to the page you want to test, by-passing any UI complexity: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#hybrid-tests

Else you can try other options, such as switching tabs: [How I can open and close next/new tab in active browser session in Karate UI Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66813199/143475)

or JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

See if you can contribute code to Karate or you can look for another framework.