Karate Javascript script call returning circular reference error
When calling the following JS script to open a new tab, it throws a circular reference error:
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: javascript failed twice: {"value":{"error":"javascript error","message":"javascript error: circular reference\n  (Session info: chrome=128.0.6613.119)","stacktrace":"0   chromedriver                        0x00000001024af9a8 cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1887096\n1   chromedriver                        0x00000001024a7e10 cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1855456\n2   chromedriver                        0x00000001020acbe0 cxxbridge1$string$len + 89508\n3   chromedriver                        0x00000001020b1c90 cxxbridge1$string$len + 110164\n4   chromedriver                        0x00000001020b3680 cxxbridge1$string$len + 116804\n5   chromedriver                        0x000000010212b0cc cxxbridge1$string$len + 606864\n6   chromedriver                        0x000000010212a4a4 cxxbridge1$string$len + 603752\n7   chromedriver                        0x00000001020e5a08 cxxbridge1$string$len + 322508\n8   chromedriver                        0x00000001020e666c cxxbridge1$string$len + 325680\n9   chromedriver                        0x0000000102476068 cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1651256\n10  chromedriver                        0x000000010247a99c cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1669996\n11  chromedriver                        0x000000010245b1fc cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1541068\n12  chromedriver                        0x000000010247b26c cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1672252\n13  chromedriver                        0x000000010244c810 cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1481184\n14  chromedriver                        0x0000000102499108 cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1794776\n15  chromedriver                        0x0000000102499284 cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1795156\n16  chromedriver                        0x00000001024a7aac cxxbridge1$str$ptr + 1854588\n17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000197ab9f94 _pthread_start + 136\n18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000197ab4d34 thread_start + 8\n"}}
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.eval(WebDriver.java:160)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.eval(WebDriver.java:167)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.script(WebDriver.java:489)
- <js>.:anonymous(Unnamed:1)

Here is the statement in the Karate feature file to do a basic new tab using JS and switch to it:
* script("window.open('', '_blank');")
  And switchPage(1)


I think the first argument cannot be empty. Try this:
* script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank')")

Based on an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813293/143475

No difference there... wondering if it's an issue with chromedriver

@AIExplorer maybe. do consider debugging and contributing a solution or code via a PR
