# How to switch from Java selenium webdriver to Karate driver inside the same Karate script

Tags: karate

I am trying to handle a browser popup which comes at the top of a browser. The API mentioned in Karate doesn't work, hence I used Selenium webdriver inside Karate to handle it and I was able to handle it. However, when I try to switch to Karate driver in the same script to execute rest of the code, it doesn't work.

I called Selenium Java inside Karate script to handle the window switch and then I tried to switch to Karate driver inside the same script, but switching to Karate driver didn't work.

Background:

- def PopupHandler = Java.type('com.example.PopupHandler')

Scenario:
Given driver 'https://www.example.com'

- driver.click('button#popupButton') // Click on the button that triggers the popup
- Java.call(PopupHandler.handlePopup, driver)

How to switch to Karate driver after this statement?

Comment: see if this helps, else please allow other to replicate your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727612/143475

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas for the response. I have tried switchPage and it works for a new tab, however it doesn't work for a popup window which opens inside another window. For any authentication app, microsoft browser popup window appear to accept it. switchPage doesn't switch to that window when used. Hence, i tried using Java webdriver inside Karate and then used the window handles to switch to the browser window. However, i cannot switch to the Karate driver after that. Please let me know if it can be done in any other way.

Comment: sorry, can't proceed without a way to replicate. my suggestion try to get support from your company to contribute code to karate, that's the best way forward. so far no team has ever reported this reuirement